# First order logic variable without quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In First Order Logic is it possible to define a formula as :

```
p(X,a)
```

where **X** is a variable and **a** a constant ? Or i must use quantifiers if i use a variable in a predicate ?

Comment: Yes; a *predicate* symbol has one or more "holes", i.e. argument-places (depending on its [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) ) thus must be "filled" with *terms*, where a *term* is : either (i) a variable, or (ii) a constant, or (iii) a "complex" term formed with *function* symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a formula, yes. It's just not sentence.

A sentence is a formula without any free variables. But syntactically, we build up sentences using formulas. For example, a sentence like $\forall x \ p(x,a)$ starts with the formula $p(x,a)$, and then adds a quantifier.

Comment: In prolog a formula like this is implicitly universally quantified. But without the universal quantifier what is its meaning ?

Comment: @Qwerto That's right, in prolog it's seen as universally quantified, but not so in first-order logic. In FOL, without the quantifier, it does not make a claim ... which is why it is not a sentence; it's only a formula.

Comment: So "in practice" what is its use ?

Comment: @Qwerto One is as I indicated:  it's an intermediate step in the step-by-step syntactic construction of sentences. But another is that while formulas that have free variables don't have a truth-value, we can nevertheless extend our notions of equivalence, consequence, etc. to formulas in general. For example, it is clear that $\neg \neg p(x,a)$ is equivalent to $p(x,a)$. And that allows us to apply equivalence principles when rewriting statements, e.g. since $\neg \neg p(x,a)$ is equivalent to $p(x,a)$, it follows that $\forall x \ \neg \neg p(x,a)$ is equivalent to $\forall x \ p(x,a)$

Comment: @Qwerto These equivalences between formulas are of particular importance when you use prenex l;aws to pull out quantifiers, since there you're almost always pulling quantifiers over free variables. For example, if I have the sentence $\exists x (P(x) \land \forall y (Q(y) \rightarrow R(x,y)))$, then I can pull the quantifier out to get $\exists x \forall y (P(x) \land (Q(y) \rightarrow R(x,y)))$, but only because the *formula* $P(x) \land \forall y (Q(y) \rightarrow R(x,y))$ is equivalent to the formula $\forall y  (P(x) \land (Q(y) \rightarrow R(x,y)))$